# Check power consumption of individual hardware components

Tags: power-management

I can check the total average power consumption of my machine using powerstat. However how do I check the power consumption of the individual components of my computer, like say the wlan-card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the individual-component-power-usage monitoring circuitry is not designed into modern computers, you're left with:

Monitor system power usage with the device connected.

Monitor system power usage with the device disconnected.

Some devices (CPU, RAM, hardware buses, etc) can't be measured with this technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [powertop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerTOP), but at least on my laptop there is no estimation for wlan, see iwlwifi in the screenshot. But if you consider how many small devices have wifi in these days, it's consumption will be probably very small.

[image: Screenshot]